# Python code calls C library that create OS threads, which eventually call Python callbacks

Tags: python, c, callback, pthreads

If the one and only Python interpreter is in the middle of executing a bytecode when the OS dispatches another thread, which calls a Python callback - what happens? Am I right to be concerned about the reliability of this design?

Comment: Are you talking about the GIL? See this [pycon video on how the GIL works](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Obt-vMVdM8s)

Comment: I'm analyzing an existing C library. Neither threading nor multiprocessing is used on the Python side. That's what is causing me some concerns.

Comment: I have a merely mortal understanding of the GIL. I'm assuming there are excellent reasons that it is managed by threading. The absence of that management here worries me.

Answer (score 3):

In general situations, the C library needs to call `PyEval_InitThreads()` to gain GIL before spawning any thread that invokes python callbacks. And the callbacks need to be surrounded with `PyGILState_Ensure()` and `PyGILState_Release()` to ensure safe execution.

However, if the C library is running within the context of, say, a python C extension, then there are simple cases where it is safe to omit GIL manipulation at all.

Think of this calling sequence: 1) python code calls C function `foo()`, 2) `foo()` spawns *one and only one* thread that runs another C function `bar()`, which calls back to python code, and 3) `foo()` always joins or cancels the thread running `bar()` before returns.

In such a case, it is safe to omit GIL manipulation. Because `foo()` *owns* the GIL (i.e. implicitly borrowed from the python code that calls it) during its lifecycle, and the execution of python callbacks within the lifecycle of `foo()` is serialized (i.e. only one callback thread and python code does not incorporate `threading`).

Comment: Only one Python thread has GIL at a time. What happens with GIL if there are several non-python threads?

Comment: Thanks liuyu! Modifying the C to call PyEval_InitThreads() is probably feasible, now that I can clearly state the problem.

Comment: @Sebastian, Python's GIL is a kind of critical section from the perspective of C threads. Whether a C thread should lock the critical section (gain the GIL) depends on whether it needs to access resource (Python API's) in the critical section. Nothing happens by default.

Comment: by default a C extension function called from Python holds GIL (if it exists). My question what happens if it spawns non-python threads. Your answer implies that the GIL is inherited by a child thread i.e., you can call a Python callback in it. It seems you should always wrap a Python callback in a non-python thread using `PyGILState_*` functions otherwise a Python calback might call [PyEval_InitThreads() in a non-main thread that doesn't hold GIL](http://docs.python.org/c-api/init.html#PyEval_InitThreads). The docs say it shouldn't happen.

Comment: To @Sebastian, please note from @phunctor's comment to the question that the python code under discussion does NOT incorporate `threading` or `multiprocessing` on the Python side. So in this *special case*, the callback is guaranteed to be sequential. And what I was saying is that in such *special cases*, GIL manipulation might be safely omitted. Otherwise, you are definitely right!

Comment: Also please note from the docs that, if the python interpreter disabled thread support at compile time, `PyEval_InitThreads()` may not even be available. So there are possible use cases that GIL manipulation is intentionally omitted by some (multi-theaded) C extension modules, that is when portability is a primary concern.

Comment: I agree if there is only one thread in Python (no GIL) and C threads access Python functions sequentially then it should work. Otherwise [there could be errors. I've created a small C extension module to demonstrate it](https://gist.github.com/3471699).

Comment: @Sebastian, just reviewed your demo. I believe the KeyError and deadlock cases can be avoided. Check this out https://gist.github.com/3473376