# Embedded Boost::Python and C++ : run in parallel

Tags: c++, python, multithreading, loops, boost-python

How do I run C++ and Boost::Python code in parallel without problems?

Eg in my game I'd want to execute Python code in parallel with C++ code; if the embedded Python interpreter's code executes a blocking loop, like `while(True): pass`, the C++ code would still be running and processing frames to render with its own loop.

I tried with `boost::thread` and `std::thread` but unless I joined these threads with the main thread the program would crash...

Any suggestions or examples?

Comment: You have to join a std::thread before it is destructed.

Comment: I do, but how do I keep the c++ code from terminating? Using a `while(!terminated)` loop?

Comment: That might work, but you might need a way of telling it to stop at some point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea to use a second thread for the Python interpreter should just work. Make sure you use the [PyGILState_Ensure](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html#PyGILState_Ensure)/Release mechanisms everywhere you wish to run code that will invoke any Python or Boost::Python code. You have more details on [this other SO thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470367/pyeval-initthreads-in-python-3-how-when-to-call-it-the-saga-continues-ad-naus).

Comment: It works now, adding a single line! So I don't need to relase the lock at the end?

Comment: Happy it worked out for you. The recommendation is that you release it and re-acquire it every time you need it.

Comment: To complement, we use things like smart locks to do this. See here for an example: https://github.com/idiap/bob/blob/master/src/python/gil.cc

Comment: Upvoting the comment and the answer would be awesome then! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the multiprocessing module in python so that you get a separate GIL for each python thread.

Comment: I'd prefer avoiding Python modules as much as possible, because of the need to redistribute them :)