# CPython - locking the GIL in the main thread

Tags: python, c, cpython

The documentation for CPython thread support is frustratingly contradictory and sparse.

In general, it seems that everyone agrees that multi-threaded C applications which embed Python must always acquire the GIL before calling the Python interpreter.  Typically, this is done by:

```
PyGILState_STATE s = PyGILState_Ensure();

/* do stuff with Python */

PyGILState_Release(s);
```

The docs pretty much spell this out very plainly: https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html#non-python-created-threads

However, in practice, getting a multi-threaded C program that embeds Python to actually work smoothly is another story.  There seem to be a lot of quirks and surprises, even if you follow the docs exactly.

For example, it seems that behind-the-scenes, Python distinguishes between the "main thread" (which I guess is the thread that calls `Py_Initialize`) and other threads.  Specifically, any attempt to acquire the GIL and run Python code in the "main" thread has consistently failed when I attempt to do so - (at least with Python 3.x), the program aborts with a `Fatal Python error: drop_gil: GIL is not locked` message, which is silly because of course the GIL is locked!

Example:

```
int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyEval_InitThreads();
    PyEval_ReleaseLock();

    assert(PyEval_ThreadsInitialized());

    PyGILState_STATE s = PyGILState_Ensure();

    const char* command = "x = 5\nfor i in range(0,10): print(x*i)";
    PyRun_SimpleString(command);

    PyGILState_Release(s);
    Py_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

This simple program aborts with a "GIL is not locked error", even though I clearly locked it.  However, if I spawn another thread, and attempt to acquire the GIL in that thread, everything works.

So CPython seems to have an (undocumented) concept of a "main thread", which is somehow different from secondary threads spawned by C.

**Question**: Is this documented anywhere?  Has anyone had any experience that would shed some light on what exactly the rules are for acquiring the GIL, and if being in the "main" thread versus a child thread is supposed to have any bearing on this?

PS: Also, I've noted that `PyEval_ReleaseLock` is a [deprecated API call](https://docs.python.org/dev/c-api/init.html#c.PyEval_ReleaseLock), yet I've not seen any alternative which actually works.  If you don't call `PyEval_ReleaseLock` after calling `PyEval_InitThreads`, your program immediately hangs.  However, the [newer alternative mentioned in the docs](https://docs.python.org/dev/c-api/init.html#c.PyEval_ReleaseLock), `PyEval_SaveThread` has never worked in practice for me - it immediately seg faults, at least if I call it in the "main" thread".

Comment: This question implies that you shouldn't call PyEval_ReleaseLock at all: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15470367/321772

Comment: You should probably ask [python-dev](https://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/python-dev).

Answer (score 5):

> This simple program aborts with a "GIL is not locked error", even though I clearly locked it.

You locked the GIL, but then you proceeded to release it in `PyGILState_Release`, which means you invoked `Py_Finalize` **without** the GIL held.

> Has anyone had any experience that would shed some light on what exactly the rules are for acquiring the GIL

The intended way to think of the GIL is that, once you invoke `PyEval_InitThreads()`, **someone** always holds the GIL, or has released it only temporarily using `Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS` and `Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15471525/1600898) for an extended discussion of a very similar confusion.

In your case the correct way to write the sample program would be as follows:

```
#include <Python.h>

static void various()
{
    // here we don't have the GIL and can run non-Python code without
    // blocking Python

    PyGILState_STATE s = PyGILState_Ensure();
    // from this line, we have the GIL, and we can run Python code

    const char* command = "x = 5\nfor i in range(0,10): print(x*i)";
    PyRun_SimpleString(command);

    PyGILState_Release(s);
    // from this line, we no longer have the GIL
}

int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyEval_InitThreads();
    // here we have the GIL
    assert(PyEval_ThreadsInitialized());

    Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
    // here we no longer have the GIL, although various() is free to
    // (temporarily) re-acquire it
    various();
    Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS

    // here we again have the GIL, which is why we can call Py_Finalize 
    Py_Finalize();

    // at this point the GIL no longer exists
    return 0;
}
```