# How can I start a Python thread FROM C++?

Tags: python, c++, multithreading, boost-python

Note that I'm constrained to use Python 2.6. I have a Python 2.6 application that uses a C++ multi-threaded API library built with boost-python. My use-case was simply to execute a Python function callback from a C++ boost thread but despite the many different attempts and researching all the available online resources I haven't found any way that works. All the proposed solutions revolve around a different combination of the functions: `Py_Initialize*`, `PyEval_InitThreads`, `PyGILState_Ensure`, `PyGILState_Release` but after trying all possible combinations nothing works in practice e.g.

- [Embedding Python in multi-threaded C++ applications](https://danielpocock.com/embedding-python-multi-threaded-cpp) with code [here](http://svn.resiprocate.org/viewsvn/resiprocate/main/repro/plugins/pyroute/)
- [PyEval_InitThreads in Python 3: How/when to call it? (the saga continues ad nauseum)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470367/pyeval-initthreads-in-python-3-how-when-to-call-it-the-saga-continues-ad-naus)

Therefore, this question: how can I start and run a Python thread **from C++**? I basically want to: create it, run it with a Python target function object and forget about it.

Is that possible?

Comment: May spawning a new process work?

Comment: No, I have to create a thread within the interpreter application process I am attached to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the OP [How to call Python from a boost thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41240610/how-to-call-python-from-a-boost-thread) also answers this OP or DP (Derived:)). It clearly demonstrates how to start a thread from C++ that callbacks to Python. **I have tested it and works perfectly** though needs adaptation for pre-C++11. It uses Boost Python, is indeed an all inclusive 5* answer and the [example source code is here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/510b063774bb5dea).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the text below from your question:

> Run a Python thread from C++? I basically want to: create it, run it with a Python target function object and forget about it.

You may find useful to simply spawn a process using [`sytem`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/system):

```
system("python myscript.py")
```

And if you need to include arguments:

```
string args = "arg1 arg2 arg3 ... argn"
system("python myscript.py " + args)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call `PyEval_InitThreads` from your init routine (and leave the GIL held).  Then, you can spawn a pthread (using boost), and in that thread, call `PyGILState_Ensure`, then call your python callback (`PyObject_CallFunction`?), release any returned value or deal with any error (`PyErr_Print`?), release the GIL with `PyGILState_Release`, and let the thread die.

```
void *my_thread(void *arg)
{
    PyGILState_STATE gstate;
    PyObject *result;

    gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();

    if ((result = PyObject_CallFunction(func, NULL))) {
        Py_DECREF(result);
    }
    else {
        PyErr_Print();
    }

    PyGILState_Release(gstate);

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't answer this OP, it is another possible combination of what I have done already many many times and in many different ways but OK I will post a question update with what I get. Your answer has a couple of new spices to the Python-C++-concurrent-sup

Comment: So you haven't tried *all* possible solutions then?

Comment: Ah I know what the different spice is .. you are basically asking me to drop boost python and use the Python C interface directly. You add more complexity to my already complex problem :D. I have a `boost::python::object func` that I can simply call like `func(params)`

Comment: Fine, replace the call to `PyObject_CallFunction` with the boost "simplification" layer, but you still need to deal with the GIL.  Either use the C API directly for that, or use the RAII approach shown [here](https://www.medin.name/blog/2012/02/12/embedding-python-inside-a-multithreaded-c-program/)

Comment: It looks like boost will turn python exceptions into the C++ exception `error_already_set`, so you should definitely use the RAII approach to release the GIL.  You will likely want to catch the exception unless you prefer your program to terminate...

Comment: You also need to be aware that boost python object destructors call `Py_DECREF` which can only be done  while holding the GIL.  Pay close attention to the order in which c++ destroys the RAII GIL wrapper and the boost python object wrapper returned from the boost python function object.