# Calling Py_EndInterpreter from a C worker thread

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, python-embedding

The deprecation of Python's `PyEval_ReleaseLock` has introduced a problem in our codebase: We want to terminate a Python interpreter from a C callback function using `Py_EndInterpreter`

So to do that, [Python's Docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/c-api/init.html#c.Py_EndInterpreter) say that you must hold the GIL when calling this function:

> **void Py_EndInterpreter(PyThreadState *tstate)**
>
> Destroy the (sub-)interpreter represented by the given thread state. The given thread state must be
>   the current thread state. See the discussion of thread states below. When the call returns, the
>   current thread state is NULL. All thread states associated with this interpreter are destroyed. (**The
>   global interpreter lock must be held** before calling this function and is **still held when it returns.**)
>   Py_FinalizeEx() will destroy all sub-interpreters that haven’t been explicitly destroyed at that point.

Great! So we call `PyEval_RestoreThread` to restore our thread state to the thread we're about to terminate, and then call `Py_EndInterpreter`.

```
// Acquire the GIL
PyEval_RestoreThread(thread);

// Tear down the interpreter.
Py_EndInterpreter(thread);

// Now what? We still hold the GIL and we no longer have a valid thread state.
// Previously we did PyEval_ReleaseLock here, but that is now deprecated.
```

The documentation for `PyEval_ReleaseLock` says that we should either use `PyEval_SaveThread` or `PyEval_ReleaseThread`.
`PyEval_ReleaseThread`'s documentation says that the input thread state must not be NULL. Okay, but we can't pass in the recently deleted thread state.

`PyEval_SaveThread` will hit a debug assertion if you try to call it after calling `Py_EndInterpreter`, so that's not an option either.

So, we've currently implemented a hack to get around this issue - we save the thread state of the thread that calls `Py_InitializeEx` in a global variable, and swap to it after calling `Py_EndInterpreter`.

```
// Acquire the GIL
PyEval_RestoreThread(thread);

// Tear down the interpreter.
Py_EndInterpreter(thread);

// Swap to the main thread state.
PyThreadState_Swap(g_init.thread_state_);
PyEval_SaveThread(); // Release the GIL. Probably.
```

What's the proper solution here? It seems that embedded Python is an afterthought for this API.

Similar question: [PyEval_InitThreads in Python 3: How/when to call it? (the saga continues ad nauseam)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470367)